# How to make an "in" statement inclusive-only in SQL

Tags: sql, querying

**EDITED:

Read `table_row` as `table_column`**  (Dudu Markovitz)

---

I have a subset of values that I want to evaluate against a row in SQL.

```
Select count(*) cnt  
from table_name c
where c.table_row in ('value 1','value 2', 'value 3')
and other statements;
```

This works fine as long as I only want to determine if "table_row" contains one of those three values.

What I want, however, is to determine if table_row contains **only** those values.

Is there any SQL statement that can perform an inclusive-only 'in' statement, so that for the "cnt" in the above query, I will only get a result if 'table_row' is in the set indicated by the query?

Comment: Are you saying where 1 row contains all 3 values, or any of the 3 values exist in any row?

Comment: Provide sample data and the desired output.

Comment: `table_row` is a terrible name for a column, by the way...

Comment: That is not logical. You cant check that a value is the same as all the values in a range. To illustrate lets assume a record has the value `value 1` in the column `table_row`, how could it then also be `value 2` and `value 3`. There is always but one value in a record's column. If you think there are multiple values then you are no longer thinking of a column but of a linked table.

Comment: Your question is nonsense. What you are asking for is exactly what the `IN` condition does. As @PM77-1 suggests, please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would do?

```
select count(*) cnt  
from table_name c
where
not exists (
    select * table_name t
    where COALESCE(table_row,'-1') != 'value 1' 
    and COALESCE(table_row,'-1') != 'value 2' 
    and COALESCE(table_row,'-1') != 'value 3'
)
and other statements;
```

It looks like of weird as the subquery is not linked to the parent query but... It should work.

Comment: Almost... :-) what if table_row  can be NULL?

Comment: Updated... meny ugly

Comment: Fair, but not bullet proof. In Oracle for example empty string is treated as NULL

Comment: God, I worked with mysql for too long, you're absolutely right

Answer (score 0):

You can use Having clause. Below is a pseudocode.

```
SELECT Employees.LastName, COUNT(Orders.OrderID) AS NumberOfOrders FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Employees
ON Orders.EmployeeID=Employees.EmployeeID
GROUP BY LastName
HAVING LastName in ('Davolio','Fuller')
```

Comment: This is, functionally, the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you might looking for -
Show the result of the count only if contains no other value then 'value 1', 'value 2' and 'value 3'

```
select  count(*) as cnt  
from    table_name c
where   c.mycol in ('value 1','value 2', 'value 3')
        -- ...and other statements
having  count(*) = 
        count(case when c.table_row in ('value 1','value 2', 'value 3') then 1 end)
```

And you might also just want to see the counts

```
select  count(*)                                                                    as cnt  
       ,count(case when c.table_row in ('value 1','value 2', 'value 3') then 1 end) as cnt_val
from    table_name c
where   c.mycol in ('value 1','value 2', 'value 3')
        -- ...and other statements
```